# An unusual use-case for HMAC as compression function in web browsers

Tags: hash, hmac, merkle-damgaard, compression-function

It's an unfortunate fact that, right now (2019), browsers don't expose standardized streaming hashing interfaces in `SubtleCrypto`. The only way to hash a file, is to load it into an `ArrayBuffer` in its entirety, which for large files, this could be prohibitvely costly memory-wise.

To get around it, I'm thinking of building a custom hash function using HMAC as its compression function, in a usual Merkal-Damgaard construct.

$
\text{compress}(IV, M) = \text{HMAC-SHA256}_{IV}(M)\\
IV_i = \text{compress}(IV_{i-1},M_i) \\
IV_0 = \text{00h}^\text{hashlen} \\
H(M_1|M_2|...|M_n) = IV_n
$

The specific questions I have are:

Q1: Do I still need to include file length in the final block? I'm guessing no because the HMAC compression function already length-pad my message during processing.

Q2: What are the characteristics of such construct with regard to length-extension attack? I'm using SHA256 because it's standardized in Web Crypto, and it's length-extendable, so I wouldn't be bothering to defend against it in my HMAC-Hash construct.

Comment: …what are you really trying to do?  Why are you trying to hash a large file?  Is there a secret key involved?  What security properties are you hoping for?

Comment: I'm trying to hash a large file part-by-part with out loading it entirely into memory. There is no key involved, I just want a streaming hash function. It should be as secure as SHA256.

Comment: ‘As secure’ meaning what?  Are you hoping for collision resistance?  Pseudorandomness under a secret prefix?  A construction with random oracle indifferentiability?  What are you planning to do with the hash once you compute it?

Comment: Same collision and preimage resistance as SHA256, randomness isn't necessary. It's used to identify files in a file upload system so that the same files that had previously been partially uploaded can restart from where it left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collision resistance of this hash will be the collision resistance of $\operatorname{HMAC-SHA256}_{IV}(M)$. Beware of the fact that pre-hashing of the key *is* a thing with HMAC, so $$\operatorname{HMAC-SHA256}_{\text{ReallyLongIV}}(M)=\operatorname{HMAC-SHA256}_{\operatorname{SHA256}(\text{ReallyLongIV})}(M)$$

> Do I still need to include file length in the final block?

To get the benefits of the Merkle-Damgard proof? Yes, because abstractly your HMAC invocations are just compression function calls.
However if you're willing to assume that it's impossible / really hard to find $(IV',m')$ such that $\operatorname{HMAC-SHA256}_{IV'}(m')=IV_0$ then you don't need to pad with the message length. You see this when you follow the standard Merkle-Damgard proof. That is go backwards through the message and if at any point the inputs differ but the outputs match you got a collision in the underlying compression function. There will be a point where one message may be shorter than the other, assumning both end with the same suffix - because otherwise there would be a collision - both end up at $IV_0$ at some point and as one message is longer one of them must expose a preimage to $IV_0$.

> What are the characteristics of such construct with regard to length-extension attack?

It's a standard Merkle-Damgard, so it has the same length-extension weakness. To fix this you could e.g. use [HAIFA](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/278) and use $C(S,M,P)=\operatorname{HMAC-SHA256}_S(P\mathbin\|M)$ as HAIFA's compression function for some fixed-length integer $P$.

Comment: I thought if we could find an IV-m tuple that hashes to arbitrary intermediate state resulting from a different IV-m tuple, then there's a collision. Does it have to be $IV_0$ as mentioned in the current answer?

Comment: So the basic premise of this answer is that it's hard to find two different IV-m pairs that map to the same output. Then _in addition_ there's a special case needed for $IV_0$ that it's hard to find any IV-m pair that maps specifically to $IV_0$. This would mean (among potentially other things) that it's unwise to choose $IV_0$ as the result of some application of the compression function.